# Smarty call object method in if statement

Tags: php, smarty

So im trying to assign a object to smarty.

```
    $a = FrameworkCore::getUserSessionObj(); // returns the object ofc
    $smarty->registerObject('global_session',$a);



  {if $global_session->isLoggedIn eq true}
    LOGGED IN
  {else}
    NO
  {/if}
```

Now im trying to put the method call into if statement, but it won't work. Tried it multiple time with different values and other methods.

The output of the method call works fine (see below).

```
  {global_session->getType}
  {global_session->isLoggedIn}
```

So it seems the/my failure is in the if statement, but i can't get it working.

Comment: What is the output / error you are experiencing?

Comment: that code that i posted throws no error. If i remove the  dollar sign inside the if statement, it throws the error,  that resource is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [`registerObject()`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.object.tpl) you will add them like custom functions. So you can use expressions like `{global_session->getType}` or `{global_session->isLoggedIn}` like you did. But you can't use it like variables as in `{$global_session}` because you haven't assigned such a variable with `assign()`. This also means you can't write code like:

```
{if global_session->isLoggedIn eq true}
...
{/if}
```

Check the [manual of objects in smarty](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.objects.tpl):

> - One way is to register objects to the template, then use access them via syntax similar to custom functions.
> - The other way is to `assign()` objects to the templates and access them much like any other assigned variable.

So when you want to use the object as a variable use `assign()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add parentheses to your method names, as you would in PHP.

```
{if $global_session->isLoggedIn()}
    LOGGED IN
{else}
    NO
{/if}
```